# grep the count of occurences of a pattern for report generation

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I want to find a specific pattern of occurences in multiple files and need to generate a report. For example, if there are two files say test1.txt and text2.txt. I will have to go through the files and look the count for "samplePattern" in each and every file. And create a report like

```
<filename>  <count>
text1.txt   3
text2.txt   10
```

I have used the following command in the directory where I have all the files:

```
grep -lr -o 'samplePattern'  | wc -l
```

But this gives me a cumulative count of all the 'samplePattern' in all the files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use `grep -c 'samplePattern' *`, which will count per file ?